# How does a proxy know where to forward the requests to?

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp, udp, network-protocols

When a proxy receives a connection how does the proxy know where to forward the request to?
For example in `Java` we can set a system property for proxy.
So we set the `IP` of the proxy and the request is send to the proxy, but how does a proxy know where to forward the actual request to?

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of types of proxies, and each uses a different approach to communicate to the proxy server what it wants to do.

HTTP proxies understand HTTP only, and do not try to proxy packets, but instead HTTP commands like connect, get, post, etc. They create an entirely new packet addressed at the lower layers from themselves to the destination server. When a client initiates a connection, the first packet of the http flow contains the CONNECT verb. the proxy recieves it, does a dns lookup on it if needed, and builds a packet to send to the remote server using the http commands and data flow from the packets it receives from the client.

SOCKS proxies perform tunneling above the session layer, so the client configures a layer 5 header which tells the proxy where you want to connect, transport protocol info, and passes any authentication the proxy requires. The client places the Layer 6/7 datagrams into the layer 5 segment's data region, and sends it to the proxy. the proxy receives it, creates a new packet (without a SOCKS header) addressed to the remote server, places the layer6/7 data units from the client packet into the new packet, and sends it to the destination server. SOCKS proxies don't work for all upper layer protocols, but they will proxy most lower layer protocols including tcp and udp.

Comment: `CONNECT` is standard header?

Comment: its an HTTP command. if you look at HTTP as a layer 7 protocol and ignore all the rest of the network stack, HTTP is just a set of Text commands and responses. see here for the standard HTTP commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227461%28v=vs.60%29.aspx . it may help to note that if you use telnet to connect to a web server at port 80, you could issue a command like 'GET \index.html HTTP/1.1' it will return the markup of the page index.html. a CONNECT command tells the client to connect to a server. after that, the client can GET, POST, or whatever.

Comment: to answer your question precisely though, no, HTTP commands and their responses are the actual data of the packets (they go in the layer 7 datagram in the data region from an encapsulated point of view) rather than fields in a well formed header.

Comment: `a CONNECT command tells the client to connect to a server. after that, the client can GET, POST, or whatever` So the proxy keeps some kind of session for each client?

Comment: TCP handles session. at Layer7 you can think of a connection like a tube you yell through to talk to a guy in the next apartment. the connection exists as an IO stream, and by writing to that stream, you are sending a communication, and you read data off it to read a response. how that breaks down into packets is unimportant at this level. This is why TCP protocols like HTTP are called connection-orriented. once the connection is established, you just read and write data to the network stream as needed.

Comment: Ok but the `CONNECT` is send only once and in the next `GET` or `POST` the proxy some how "magically" knows to forward to the server mentioned in the initial `CONNECT`?

Comment: no magic about it, but I think you understand enough to get by. I think about it differently because I've written network services before, so I understand it both from the network jockey's perspective, and the programmers. just remember, when you create the TCP connection to the a specific port on proxy, that connection remains open, and all your http commands pass through it, so the server is not confused as to what flow the gets and responses are related to.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it is the TCP connection *may* close at any time. `HTTP` protocol says that the connection *may* close from either party. I am trying to write a proxy and I am confused on this details. So if the connection is closed the client would resend a `CONNECT`?

Comment: that is correct. usually the client recieves a "connection reset by peer" message in that case.

Comment: I have one last question. Is it possible to implement the proxy server in `TCP` level agnostic of application protocol? I.e. could it be a `TCP` proxy handling `HTTP` traffic? I am interested in building a proxy that could handle both `TCP` and `UDP` traffic.I though to ask since you mentioned in your previous comment that you have experience implementing network services.

Comment: well, keeping in mind that the developer usually operates at layer 7 and doesn't go too far beneath it, yes, what you are describing is a SOCKS-like proxy. it would be hard to tunnel below layer 5 without some kind of pre-established tunnel (stunnel, SSH, etc). I'd look closely at socks and see if you can make it fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**How does http proxy know destination/target url or where to forward requests to?**

Web app(client) flow with proxy(server) starts from `HTTP CONNECT` request sent to the proxy server e.g. `CONNECT www.my-proxy.com:443 HTTP/1.1`.

After connection is established, web app(client) sends normal `HTTP` requests to the proxy e.g.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.my-destination.com
```

and the proxy handles/forwards them further to the destination.